# Melting ice off of trucks fast

Tags: everyday-chemistry, water, phase

When a truck comes into the shop with extreme ice that is rock hard, is there a way to remove it fast? Any tricks of the trade?

Comment: There are plenty of ways of doing it, most of which are not practical. This being a chemistry site, I don't think that chemistry will be of much use in removing pre-exitant ice. I would just use hot water via hose and sprayer. However, chemistry may be able to provide an anti-icing coating that helps prevent the buildup of ice before it reaches your shop. Is that something you are interested in?

Comment: Are there any restrictions? I have suggestions for how to remove the ice in a zippy instant...but it would probably not be very good for anyone in the vicinity.

Answer (score 6):

Water has a high heat capacity, so I agree with JoeHobbit that a spray of hot water via hose would probably work best. A power washer that is capable of heating the water might be worth getting. A secondary advantage of doing this is that the water spray would remove accumulated road salt, which accelerates corrosion. Short of that, a space heater that blows hot air on the truck would be a less effective but also less messy solution. A moving stream of hot water or air should be far more effective than static immersion.

Small amounts of ice deposits can be removed with an aerosol deicer spray.

See, there is actually a lot of chemistry going on here.